# Does the word 'famous' imply that it's something good?

Tags: word-meaning

There are the words 'famous' and 'infamous'. The latter clearly suggests that what is being described is morally bad. What about the former? Is it neutral or does it implicate that it's necessarily good? For example, I suspect that saying 'the famous concentration camp Buchenwald' would be disturbing for some people. Putting this example aside, there are instances where you just want to point out that many people have heard about something while avoiding giving your personal moral assessment of it.

Comment: I would say that 'famous' is neutral or positive.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is the Buchenwald example inappropriate, in your view?

Comment: Calling Buchenwald 'famous' would be problematic. You can't be neutral about genocide, and being positive is unacceptable. Buchenwald is notorious.